# Get offset of a file, using 5 characters of a custom dictionary

Tags: c#, offset

I want to get a string offset of file, but the string offset changes file to file.
So, I did make a custom dictionary.

```
        [0x41] = "A",
        [0x42] = "B",
        [0x43] = "C",
        [0x44] = "D",
        [0x45] = "E",
        [0x46] = "F",
        [0x47] = "G",
```

.....................
To get the offset, i want to read the file, when finds 5 sequential chars of my dictionary, stop then back -5 and then get offset.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS will not get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for *free help* to solve **your problem**. Thanks.

Comment: i am sorry, i dont mean to be unpolite with anyone.